# One login for two projects in a solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, authentication

So I have two projects in my solution, one is an ASP.Net C# Web App and the other is a Silverlight application. My question is, instead of configuring users and security for both sites with the ASP.net Web Site Administration tool, can I somehow use just one to configure users for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you simply need a shared storage mechanism for users from both sources. This would normally be a database.

Comment: I was actually about to come here to answer my own question, with pretty much this. I just changed the database it uses in Web.config to the same database I already have setup and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Added to this. The class that handles the information could also be shared for both projects, so they just have to show different UIs for a common .NET object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about in Visual Studio, but if you're deploying to IIS you can configure a forms login at a higher level and use that for each application.

Comment: Good alternative, but I got my solution. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

**Using single login is right way!**

You can already use your aspnet membership in Silverlight. We use that way and this is the right thing.By this way you can share all your membership info,such as profile,groups.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/05/10/using-asp-net-membership-in-silverlight.aspx

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Leveraging-the-ASP.NET-Membership-in-Silverlight.aspx